# Deleting a file immediately after closing it - 'Permission Denied' error

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to save an email as a Word file through a macro, and then replace this with a converted PDF file via Word. The conversion part is working fine - the issue is when I try to delete the original .doc file.

```
Dim objWrd As Object
Dim objWrdDoc As Object
Dim wrdCurrentPrinter As String

Set objWrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objWrdDoc = objWrd.Documents.Open(filePath & fileName)

''Print' file as PDF - current printer is stored so it can be reverted back afterwards
wrdCurrentPrinter = objWrd.ActivePrinter
objWrd.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print To PDF"

'File name is specified here to avoid Save As prompt. PrintToFile property is 'True'
objWrd.PrintOut , , , filePath & Replace(fileName, ".doc", ".pdf"), , , , , , , True

objWrd.ActivePrinter = wrdCurrentPrinter

objWrd.Quit
Set objWrd = Nothing

Kill filePath & fileName
```

At `Kill filePath & fileName` I get error 70 - Permission denied.

I am able to delete the file manually without any problems, and if I add a breakpoint and step through the 'Kill' line, it works when there is even a slight delay between Word closing and the Kill command. Therefore I suspect that the code is being processed so quickly so that the file is still open at the time of running the command.

I have a feeling I may need to go down the route of creating a delay, which I have been having trouble with in Outlook. Is this the likely solution or is there something else that I have missed?

Comment: any chance you work on a server in a corporate network? since the times the file is locked after closing can vary, i suspect you could add a handler that checks if `objWrdDoc.Documents.Count = 0`, otherwise loops, rather than `sleep` for a fixed amount of time.

Comment: I've always had issues if I don't Marshal.  You'll need to change variables to get it working for you, but here is an example from my "finally" blocks in all of my interop functions: [Begin Block]oBook.Close(False)
                oApp.Quit()
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oRange)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oSheet)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBook)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oBooks)
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(oApp)[End Block].  I'd start there and see if it corrects.  And I just saw it's vba tag - sorry if not helpful

Comment: You should test the code by stepping through it with F8. It will show if trying to access the file too fast is the problem. I once has a problem with deleting read only files, so if it is the case then use this before killing: `If GetAttr(filePath & fileName) And vbReadOnly Then SetAttr(filePath & fileName), vbNormal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get this to work consistently by simply closing the Word document before quitting Word altogether:

```
objWrdDoc.Close
objWrd.Quit
Set objWrd = Nothing
```

The error has not appeared since adding this line and testing with various emails.